# Could not parse configuration: /hibernate.cfg.xml hibernate.sourceforge.net

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, jsf-1.2

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
                                         "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
 <session-factory name="sessionFactory">
  <property name="hibernate.connection.pool_size">10</property>
  <property name="show_sql">true</property>
  <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</property>
  <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
  <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/bestdb</property>
  <property name="hibernate.connection.password">best123</property>
  <property name="hibernate.connection.username">best</property>
  <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect</property>
  <property name="hibernate.show_sql">false</property>
  <mapping resource="Registration.hbm.xml"/>
 </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

This is my hibernate configuration file. The error stacktrace is :

```
 org.hibernate.HibernateException: Could not parse configuration: /hibernate.cfg.xml
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.doConfigure(Configuration.java:1491)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.configure(Configuration.java:1425)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.configure(Configuration.java:1411)
    at connectionHandler.ConnectionHandler.openConnection(ConnectionHandler.java:24)
    at controller.RegistrationController.loginController(RegistrationController.java:240)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.el.parser.AstValue.invoke(AstValue.java:131)
    at org.apache.el.MethodExpressionImpl.invoke(MethodExpressionImpl.java:276)
    at com.sun.facelets.el.TagMethodExpression.invoke(TagMethodExpression.java:68)
    at javax.faces.component.MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.invoke(MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.java:88)
    at com.sun.faces.application.ActionListenerImpl.processAction(ActionListenerImpl.java:102)
    at javax.faces.component.UICommand.broadcast(UICommand.java:387)
    at org.ajax4jsf.component.AjaxViewRoot.processEvents(AjaxViewRoot.java:329)
    at org.ajax4jsf.component.AjaxViewRoot.broadcastEventsForPhase(AjaxViewRoot.java:304)
    at org.ajax4jsf.component.AjaxViewRoot.processPhase(AjaxViewRoot.java:261)
    at org.ajax4jsf.component.AjaxViewRoot.processApplication(AjaxViewRoot.java:474)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.InvokeApplicationPhase.execute(InvokeApplicationPhase.java:82)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:100)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:118)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:265)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.ajax4jsf.webapp.BaseXMLFilter.doXmlFilter(BaseXMLFilter.java:206)
    at org.ajax4jsf.webapp.BaseFilter.handleRequest(BaseFilter.java:290)
    at org.ajax4jsf.webapp.BaseFilter.processUploadsAndHandleRequest(BaseFilter.java:388)
    at org.ajax4jsf.webapp.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:515)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.jboss.web.tomcat.filters.ReplyHeaderFilter.doFilter(ReplyHeaderFilter.java:96)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:230)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:175)
    at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.SecurityAssociationValve.invoke(SecurityAssociationValve.java:182)
    at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.JaccContextValve.invoke(JaccContextValve.java:84)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
    at org.jboss.web.tomcat.service.jca.CachedConnectionValve.invoke(CachedConnectionValve.java:157)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:262)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:844)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:583)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:446)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: org.dom4j.DocumentException: hibernate.sourceforge.net Nested exception: hibernate.sourceforge.net
    at org.dom4j.io.SAXReader.read(SAXReader.java:484)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.doConfigure(Configuration.java:1481)
    ... 46 more
```

My ConnectionHandler.java code is :

```
public class ConnectionHandler {

    private static SessionFactory sesstioFactory;


    public static SessionFactory getSesstioFactory() {
        return sesstioFactory;
    }


    public static void setSesstioFactory(SessionFactory sesstioFactory) {
        ConnectionHandler.sesstioFactory = sesstioFactory;
    }


    public static void openConnection(){
        try{
            System.out.println("Trying to build session factory");
            sesstioFactory=new Configuration().configure().buildSessionFactory();
            System.out.println("Session factory built successfully");
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("----------------Problem in opening connection--------------");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    public static void closeConnection(){
        try{
            System.out.println("Trying to close session factory");
            sesstioFactory.close();
            System.out.println("Session factory closed successfully");
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("----------------Problem in opening connection--------------");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

The below snippet calls the ConnectionHandler.java :

```
ConnectionHandler.openConnection(); // Calling for opening connection
                                            // for the first time
        SessionFactory sf = ConnectionHandler.getSesstioFactory();
        Session s = sf.openSession();
        Transaction t = s.beginTransaction();
```

I don't know why it's showing error parsing configuration file. I tried changing

"http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd" **to**
"http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">

All the required jars are also included. Thank you!

Comment: Your hibernate config file looks ok. Just make sure you don't have multiple hibernate config files in your application.

Comment: Your hibernate jar in classpath doesn't contain the DTD you have specified in the cfg xml. Did you check that?

Answer (score 1):

<strike>In your `hibernate.cfg.xml` file, try changing</strike>

<strike>`<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
                                             "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">`</strike>

<strike>to this:</strike>

<strike>`<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping SYSTEM "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">`</strike>

**EDIT**:

In my original answer, I copied `DOCTYPE` from my mapping file; I should have copied from the config file instead. Thanks RAS for pointing that out.

Your config file seems correct. I am using the same `DOCTYPE` declaration:

```
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
        "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
        "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
```

And for mapping files, you can try below `DOCTYPE` declaration (if yours is different) and make sure that there is no spelling mistake:

```
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC
        "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN"
        "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">
```

Comment: Why his `hibernate.cfg.xml` should refer to `hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd` instead of `hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd`?

Comment: that's my question as well?

Comment: @Debojit Difference bw PUBLIC & SYSTEM?